# JavaFX SplitPane not working

Tags: java, javafx

I tried to implement a standard example from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html), which looks like this:

```
SplitPane sp = new SplitPane();
final StackPane sp1 = new StackPane();
sp1.getItems().add(new Button("Button One"));
final StackPane sp2 = new StackPane();
sp2.getItems().add(new Button("Button Two"));
final StackPane sp3 = new StackPane();
sp3.getItems().add(new Button("Button Three"));
sp.getItems().addAll(sp1, sp2, sp3);
sp.setDividerPositions(0.3f, 0.6f, 0.9f);
```

But in NetBeans IDE I get "cannot find symbol" message which points to lines of code where `getItems` method is used. So, I ispected `sp1` variable in IDE and see that there are no longer any `getItems`, but I do not know what to use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StackPane` does not have a `getItems` method, it uses `getChildren()`!

Comment: Thank you, sir! I wish there were no errors in official documentation :)

Comment: BTW, sir, can you, please, advise if it is possible to add a kind of arrows to splitter clicking on which it would be possible to expand and collapse regions?

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand the question, you can add Buttons and call the `setDividerPosition` method https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html#setDividerPositions(double...)

Comment: Oh, it seems like it is impossible without some terrible hacking, judging by this - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092199